# Why is MyModel.offset(n).find(20) so slow in Rails 3 with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm using Rails 3 and MySQL

I have some situations where I want to pull the first chunk of records from my model table like so:

```
MyModel.offset(10).first(50)
```

If I run this in rails console, Rails & MySQL simply stall out.

If I look at the log file while I run this in the console, I get the following!!

```
SELECT `my_models`.* FROM `my_models` LIMIT 18446744073709551615 OFFSET 10
```

instead of

```
SELECT * from my_models LIMIT 50 offset 10
```

It appears as though there's something wrong with the **LIMIT** statement.
Do I have something configured incorrectly?

Comment: Why don't you try `MyModel.skip(10).limit(50)`

Answer (score 1):

Definitely a weird bug. I've confirmed it in Rails 3.0.10 and 3.1.0. From what I can tell you're not supposed to pass a number to first, so the behavior when you do may be undefined, but I'd say what it's doing is the bad sort of undefined.

What you want to do is MyModel.offset(10).limit(50). ActiveRecord::Base#first should only be used if you want a "LIMIT 1" query to be done.

I think your console was hanging because it was trying to instantiate, then inspect and output nearly every record in that table.